# How to make rsync copy the contents of source directory without affecting the permissions of the destination folder but preserve content permissions

Tags: linux, rsync

This is what the source directory looks like:

```
[user@vm01 root]$ ll /home/user/test/
total 8
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user user 6 Dec  5 03:25 hello.txt
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user user 6 Dec  5 03:26 world.txt
```

There's a target directory created on another server.

```
/root/temp
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root       6 Dec 15 01:29 temp
```

I wish to copy all the contents of the source directory while preserving the permissions of all files but without changing the permission of /root/temp directory.

This is the command I'm using:

```
rsync -a -v --progress --partial --delete-before /home/user/test/ <another-server-ip>:/root/temp/   -z -x -D -A --numeric-ids  --inplace
```

This is preserving the permissions of the files, as expected but changes the permissions of the destination directory.

I've also tried adding changing the path to /home/user/test/* which is giving the required behavior but will not work for hidden files.

Any ideas to solve this?

Comment: What user account will you be using on the remote system for the rsync?

Comment: My idea is to use `/home/user/test/{.?*,*}` as source. ".?*" icnludes hidden files. ".?*" means all files starting with dot, but not just a dot. Weird file names e.g. beginning with - could hurt here, so I would put the src target part after all switch is closed with "--"

Comment: The root user. This is the simplified test case. I only need to avoid changing the permissions of the destination directory

Comment: Would changing the permissions on the source directory to match those on the destination directory be an option?

Comment: @Kusalananda, no unfortunately this is not expected

Comment: @gabor.zed, I'll try that

Comment: Are there subdirectories that you want to sync that you need to sync the permissions etc. of?  Or would it be ok to just ignore directory meta-data?

Comment: @Kusalananda I need to preserve all the metadata of the source directory contents. Only need to somehow skip the permissions of the source directory because for some reason I can't change the permissions of the destination directory.

Comment: @User So does "source directory contents" include the meta data relating to sub-directories (anything other than regular files)?

Comment: @Kusalananda, Yes the contents can be files and directories. All these along with their metadata needs to be transferred to the target